# Doorkeeper limit application scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I have a doorkeeper provider and I need to add some scopes that not all apps can use. I want to limit the scopes a token can ask for, to the scopes than an application has access to.

So for example, application A is an app that has "access" to the `xyz` and `abc` scopes, but application B can only "access" the scope `abc`.

All access tokens from application B might require the `abc` scope but could not ask for scope `xyz`. Access tokens from application A might have any (or both) of those scopes.

Is there any way to prevent application B from requesting scope `xyz`? Or how would you implement this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's not a particularly clean way of doing this right now within Doorkeeper.

It has been discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/317), and there are two potential patches proposed [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/pull/469) and [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/pull/492). Hopefully one of those makes it into the gem. If you need this feature urgently, people have also provided several monkey-patching solutions in the comments of those issues.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't seen your response. It's kind of sad they don't support it, but thanks for pointing me to the issue!

Comment: The PR#469 has been merged. I guess there must be a way now?